# Select sublist from list into data validation

Tags: excel, validation

I have a problem in Excel.

I have the following list and table (within named ranges):

`Food List`

```
+------------+
| Fruits     |
+------------+
| Vegetables |
+------------+
```

`Specific food`

```
+------------+-----------+
| Fruits     | Apple     |
+------------+-----------+
| Fruits     | Banana    |
+------------+-----------+
| Fruits     | Orange    |
+------------+-----------+
| Vegetables | Artichoke |
+------------+-----------+
| Vegetables | Cabbage   |
+------------+-----------+
```

`Note data is ordered by alphabetical order`

I have two cells, that will have data validation to select a food category, and then a specific food from the category.

My food category data validation formula goes like `=INDEX(Food,,1)`, which is simple enough.

However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to create the second data validation. `VLOOKUP` only gives me the first occurrence of a food category, but I can't get to the last one. If I get the last one, I can use MATCH and INDEX with the count from first occurrence to the last in order to set my number of rows.

Is there any function to get the last occurrence of a cell withing an alphabetically sorted array ?

Comment: If you do a search for dependent validation lists, you will find some useful information on setting this up. It uses a different method, but should be simpler in the long run.

Comment: I understand the results, however, I would like to keep the format to two tables, and not multiple table per category

Comment: I have more than 100 categories, and many more can be added (list/table is created with offset thus I can't manage them manually like that).

Comment: Not sure what you're doing, but to return the row number of the last of a particular item in a sorted list, you can use something like `=LOOKUP(2,1/(INDEX(Food,,1)= "Fruits"),ROW(Food))` where `Food` is your two column table.  This formula will return the row number of the last Row containing `Fruits`.

Comment: Yes that resembles the solution I came with. I'll answer my question to show what I did, however, I wanted to know if there was a "cleaner" way with Excel tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve the issue.

First, in the `food` table, I added two columns, `FirstOccurrence` and `LastOccurrence`. Since my `Specific Food` is sorted alphabetically, I can do a vlookup or match to find the first occurrence of my food category. Then, the second occurrence is given by the next first_occurrence-1 and if we are at the bottom, it's the table length.

`FirstOccurrence =MATCH(J6,INDEX(Specific_Food,,1),0)`
`LastOccurrence=IF(K7=0,ROWS(Specific_Food),K7-1)`

Where:

 `- J6 is the food category to find
 - K7 is the next first occurrence of food category`

Then, in the data validation option, we use the offset function to retrieve the sublist from our specific food table !

`=OFFSET(INDEX(Specific_Food,,2),FirstOcc-1,0,LastOcc-FirstOcc+1,1)`